# Get emacs to open R terminal on right frame

Tags: ess, r

I wanted to change the behaviour of the standard emacs C-x 3 key-binding, so that instead of dividing the existing size of the frame into two windows, I wanted emacs to double the width of the window to accommodate another frame the same size as the original. I achieved this (tolerably well, I think) with the following code (adapted from [Christian Tietze](https://christiantietze.de/posts/2022/02/split-and-resize-frame/)).

```
(defvar ljs/original-frame-width nil
  "Variable to store the original frame width.")

(defun ljs/frame-double-width (&optional frame)
   (let* ((current_width (frame-pixel-width frame))
          (monitor_width (nth 2 (frame-monitor-workarea frame)))
          (double_width (min monitor_width
                             (* 2 current_width))))
       (set-frame-width frame double_width nil t)))

(defun ljs/split-right-and-resize-frame ()
  (interactive)
  (setq ljs/original-frame-width (frame-pixel-width))
  (split-window-right)
  (ljs/frame-double-width))

(defun ljs/restore-original-dimensions ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (when ljs/original-frame-width
    (set-frame-width (selected-frame) ljs/original-frame-width nil t)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 3") 'ljs/split-right-and-resize-frame)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 1") 'ljs/restore-original-dimensions)
```

I would like my emacs to follow the behaviour just defined and mapped to C-x 3 when opening an R terminal window (entering C-Enter in emacs speaks statistics with a .R file). However, emacs continues to split the frame vertically, placing the R terminal frame underneath the frame containing the .R file I am editing. How can I tell emacs to open the iESS R terminal in the manner of the function now mapped to `C-x 3`?

Another goal is to map a new function (mapped to `C-x 4`)that, in a similar manner, adds a new frame on the right of the original frame, while splitting both frames vertically, giving me four frames of the same size. I have tried a few things but nothing comes close.

Comment: "I would like my emacs to use this option" - what option are you talking about? It's not clear from the question. Also, are you sure you are talking about frames, or perhaps you are talking about windows? Emacs terminology is different here from most other programs, so sometimes people confuse tthe two. E.g. when I press `C-enter` in an R mode buffer, which is displayed in the single window of my single frame, I end up with a single frame still, with two windows one above the other: the top window still shows my R mode buffer and the bottom window displays the R "terminal".

Comment: In brief, what Emacs calls a "frame" is what most other graphical applications call a "window". What Emacs calls a "window", most other applications call a "pane".

Comment: Thank you Nick for the clarifications. I have edited my post based on these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going on here, and posting an answer to my own question, in case it is helpful to others.

I had something like the following in my config:

```
  (defun my-ess-start-R ()
    (interactive)
    (or (assq 'inferior-ess-mode
              (mapcar 
                (lambda (buff) (list (buffer-local-value 'major-mode buff)))
                (buffer-list)))
     (progn
       (delete-other-windows)
       (setq w1 (selected-window))
       (setq w1name (buffer-name))
       (setq w2 (split-window w1 nil t))
       (R)
       (set-window-buffer w2 "*R*")
       (set-window-buffer w1 w1name))))
```

I got this code, provided originally by Felix Csaszar on the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ESSShiftEnter). It was a case of amending the code by adding my functions. The following solved the issue.

```
(defun my-ess-start-R ()
  "Start R and split the window horizontally, doubling the frame width."
  (interactive)
  (or (assq 'inferior-ess-mode
            (mapcar 
              (lambda (buff) (list (buffer-local-value 'major-mode buff)))
              (buffer-list)))
   (progn
     (delete-other-windows)
     (setq w1 (selected-window))
     (setq w1name (buffer-name))
     (setq w2 (split-window w1 nil t))
     (R)
     (set-window-buffer w2 "*R*")
     (set-window-buffer w1 w1name)
     (setq ljs/original-frame-width (frame-pixel-width))
     (ljs/frame-double-width)))) ; Double the frame width
```

Now the following code will restore the original frame-width if you kill R.

```
(defun my-restore-original-dimensions ()
  (interactive)
  (if (string-match-p "\\*R\\*" (buffer-name (current-buffer)))
      (my-ess-start-R)
    (progn
      (delete-other-windows)
      (when ljs/original-frame-width
        (set-frame-width (selected-frame) ljs/original-frame-width nil t)))))
```

Voila.